# The method setOnItemSelectedListener in the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, android

I am trying to invoke a spinner on click of list item, I could successfully "toast" on click of list item, now when i try to invoke "Spinner", it gives me below error:

> "The method
>   setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the
>   type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments
>   (new View.OnClickListener(){})"

How can i overcome it ? Below is my code :

Note : This is my adapter class and not activity class

```
 if(oi.getOptionName().contains("Other")){
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b2b2b2"));

                    option_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(View v) {                       
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //notifyDataSetChanged();                       //added

                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);

                        spinnerOsversions = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.osversions);

                        // Spinner click listener
                        spinnerOsversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(UserSurveyAdapter.this);

                        // Spinner Drop down elements
                        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
                        categories.add("Automobile");
                        categories.add("Business Services");
                        categories.add("Computers");
                        categories.add("Education");
                        categories.add("Personal");
                        categories.add("Travel");

                        // Creating adapter for spinner
                        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

                        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
                        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                        // attaching data adapter to spinner
                        spinnerOsversions.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                    }
                });
                }
```

R.layout.spinner
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/osversions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout also. I see you have this 
                        `spinnerOsversions = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.osversions);` inside onClick is spinner a child of button?

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan for looking into it. I have updated my code, it is now error free, but on click of item, i see toast coming up, but spinner isn't invoking.

Comment: to which layout does the spinner belong to. You inflate a layout but where is it attached to. Also the spinner selection listener should be moved outside of onClick

Comment: @Raghunandan - See my updated code, my spinner layout is inflated individually, not related to parent layout

Comment: So where do you see the spinner on the screen if its not attached to any container?. The event occur when you select an item and you can do that once you have it on the screen

Comment: Any idea, then how can i invoke spinner on click of list item? Any example u have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89048/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user45678).

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
spinnerOsversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

to

```
spinnerOsversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(ActivityName.this);
```

if in activity or use `getActivity()` and also make sure your activity or fragment implements the interface `OnItemSelectedListener`

Comment: Thanks Derek, I tried the same, I also tried "context" but both didn't work. The same error persists

Comment: @user45678 where do you have this code in actiivty fragment. `this` refers to annonymous inner class in your case and why is click listener inside a if condition you can have that after you click the button and do actions as you wish later

Comment: Ok, i got the point, i didn't implement "onItemSelectedListener", error solved, another issue is spinner isn't invoking. Let me check it

Comment: @user45678 i suggest you remove the if condition for that. have that inside the onClick and do action as required

Comment: @user45678 and also move the spinner selection code out of button click listener

Answer (score 0):

change

```
spinnerOsversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

to

```
spinnerOsversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(YourAdapter.this);
```

`YourAdapter` is the name of the class which implements `OnItemSelectedListener`